# Как добавить свойство filter drop-shadow в ie11?

Tags: css, css3, svg, internet-explorer, filter

Есть прозрачная картинка с декоративным шрифтом при ховере на которую накладывается `filter` со свойством `drop-shadow`.

Как применить аналогичный эффект в `ie11` ?

**Код**

```css
img:hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.5em #009af7) drop-shadow(0 0 0.2em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5));
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0.5em #009af7) drop-shadow(0 0 0.2em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5));
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a4/63/34/a46334f2069f6e1c8ae40c95b8d16776.png" alt="">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант, можно использовать [svg фильтры](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/filter), поддержка дает [зеленый цвет](https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-filters).

Ниже в примере я наложил `img` и `svg` с фильтром друг на друга, чтобы при `hover`е плавно показывать фильтр через opacity и transition. Другого варианта я пока не придумал)

```css
.filter-wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.filter-wrap:hover .filter-wrap__svg {
  opacity: 1;
}

.filter-wrap__image {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.filter-wrap__svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 200ms ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter-wrap">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a4/63/34/a46334f2069f6e1c8ae40c95b8d16776.png" alt="" class="filter-wrap__image">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 560 211" width="560" height="211" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" role="image" aria-label="Image Title" class="filter-wrap__svg">
    <defs>

      <filter id="sofGlow" height="100%" width="100%" x="0" y="0">
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" result="blurred" />
        <feFlood flood-color="#009af7" result="glowColor" />
        <feComposite in="glowColor" in2="blurred" operator="in" result="softGlow_colored" />

        <feMerge>
          <feMergeNode in="softGlow_colored"/>
          <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
        </feMerge>
      </filter>

    </defs>          
    <image width="100%" height="100%" filter="url(#sofGlow)" xlink:href="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a4/63/34/a46334f2069f6e1c8ae40c95b8d16776.png"></image>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: да, это единственный способ покрасить svg переданную в HTML с помощью `<img>`, точно также как и для svg в формате `base64`, - только с помощью фильтров (+)